# How to set a timeout within a BASH script for a process that sometimes becomes inactive?

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a bash script that runs a lot of commands/tools like convert or pdftk via CRON.

It happens quite often that e.g. pdftk becomes "stale" or "hangs" and the calling script stops proceeding.

Is there a simple way from within the bash script (via trap?) to set a time limit for execution or detect inactivity (by whatever definition) for a specific call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[BASH FAQ entry #68: "How do I run a command, and have it abort (timeout) after N seconds?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/068)

Comment: You can also use https://stackoverflow.com/a/28929295/6561343